# How to avoid warning for an unchecked conversion while fetching from ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java

How to avoid warning for an unchecked conversion while fetching from ConcurrentHashMap

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
    Set<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> kvPairs = cmap.entrySet();
```

The code snippet below, is the implementation for caching

```
Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache(cacheName);
log.trace("native cache name {}", cache.getNativeCache().getClass().getName());

ConcurrentHashMap cmap = (ConcurrentHashMap) cache.getNativeCache();
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(cmap.size());
Set<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> kvPairs = cmap.entrySet();
for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> kv : kvPairs) {
    Object value = kv.getValue();
    if (value instanceof String) {
        map.put((String) kv.getKey(), (String) value);
    }
    else if (value instanceof Newspaper) {
        map.put((String) kv.getKey(), (Newspaper) value);
    }
    else if (value instanceof ArrayList) {
        map.put((String) kv.getKey(), (ArrayList) value);
    }
    else if (value instanceof Response) {
        map.put((String) kv.getKey(), (Response) value);
    }
    else if (value instanceof PageableResponse) {
        map.put((String) kv.getKey(), (PageableResponse) value);
    }
    else {
        log.error("unable to process value {}", value.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: The article [Baeldung - Java Warning “unchecked](https://www.baeldung.com/java-unchecked-conversion) can also help you

Comment: it is not recommended to use Raw Types (`ConcurrentHashMap cmap`) from Java Language Specification [4.8. Raw Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8-400): "*The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of generics into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.*"

Comment: I was going to suggest the Baeldung article myself - it's very good. To merely "avoid the warning", there's `@SuppressWarnings(“unchecked”)`.  Another approach might be to declare a base class, and avoid using any raw types (or using "Object"!)